# Error web scraping data from Yahoo

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, yahoo-api

I am using python v3.6. for a youtube tutorial I am following along. For some reason when I run this code, I see csv file been saved(precisely 47 files) but not all of them. Can someone please point to me as to what I am doing wrong.

```
    import datetime as dt
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib import style
    from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates
    import pandas as pd
    import pandas_datareader.data as web
    import bs4 as bs
    import pickle
    import requests
    import os
    import csv
    import numpy as np 


    def tsx_tickers():
        resp = requests.get('http://web.tmxmoney.com/indices.php?section=tsx&index=%5ETSX')
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
        table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'indices-table'})
        tickers = []
        for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
            ticker = row.findAll('td')[1].text
            tickers.append(ticker.replace(".","-") + ".TO")

        with open("tsxticker.pickle", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(tickers, f)

        print(tickers)
        return tickers

def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_tsx = False):
    if reload_tsx:
        tickers = tsx_tickers()
    else:
        with open("tsxticker.pickle", "rb") as f:
            tickers = pickle.load(f)

    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
        os.makedirs('stock_dfs')

    start = dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
    end = dt.datetime(2016, 12, 13)

    for ticker in tickers:
        if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
            time.sleep(2)
            df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
            df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
        else:
            print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))
```

I keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\X\Desktop\xfile\sentdex.py", line 77, in <module>
    get_data_from_yahoo()
  File "C:\Users\X\Desktop\xfile\sentdex.py", line 72, in get_data_from_yahoo
    df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 116, in DataReader
    session=session).read()
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py", line 76, in read
    df = super(YahooDailyReader, self).read()
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 155, in read
    df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 74, in _read_one_data
    out = self._read_url_as_StringIO(url, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 85, in _read_url_as_StringIO
    response = self._get_response(url, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 120, in _get_response
    raise RemoteDataError('Unable to read URL: {0}'.format(url))
pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=OTEX.TO&a=0&b=1&c=2015&d=11&e=13&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been a Yahoo problem, because it started working again...

Answer (score 0):

When scraping, you need to be aware that many providers (big names especially, like Google, Yahoo) have countermeasures that try to thwart automated requests. Rate-limiting is a good step to avoid getting hit, but 2 seconds might even be too quick.

In any event, it's probably better to download the data in a more controlled fashion using Requests or the like, which won't choke on a valid HTTP response, and will save the content for you to look at.

```
response = requests.get('http://yahoo.com/finance...')
# server 429's because it doesn't like you, or might 200 and just have malformed content
try:
    parse(response.content)
except:
    with open('dump.log', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
    raise
```

Then you can look at the contents of the dump and see why it failed, and/or load the dump and pass it's contents to `parse()` to check it now works.

You could also switch it up and retry if you get a failed parse.

```
MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3
# ...
for ticker in tickers:
    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
        for attempt in range(MAX_ATTEMPTS):
            time.sleep(2)
            try:
                df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
            except Exception as e:
                if attempt < MAX_ATTEMPTS - 1:
                    print('Attempt {}: {}'.format(attempt + 1, str(e)))
                else:
                    raise
            else:
                break
```